# VBScript のソースコードが IE の開発ツールで文字化けする

Tags: internet-explorer, 文字化け, vbs

社内のウェブサイトを「ソースの表示（V)」でソースを確認したところ、日本語部分は下記のように文字化けが発生しています。

```
        If blnRet = True and vintMode = 0 and frmFormData.txt001.value = "" then
            'G[bZ[W쐬
            strMeg = "SAP ID͏ȗł܂            Set ctlError = frmFormData.txt001
            blnRet = False
        End If
```

何か対策がありますか。

補足　該当ページはエンコード（シフト＋JIS)で文字化けが発生せずに表示されています。
「ソースの表示（V）」をクリックしたところ、デバッガーのしたに、文字化け付きでソースが表示されています。その際のエンコードは不明です。また、IEしか対応していないです。
ソース上はすべての日本語文字が化けしています。

[image: スクリーンショット]

ご教示のほど、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　質問です。このソースはHTMLではない気がするのですが、そのあたり確認なさいましたか？

Comment: このファイル自体のエンコーディング（utf8、Shift-JIS、……）が何で、henhaoさんがソースを見るときにはどのエンコーディングで閲覧しているのでしょうか。閲覧の際、引用なさったソース部分以外の日本語は文字化けしていませんか？　全て文字化けしているのであれば、単に正しいエンコーディングで閲覧できていないからという理由が考えられます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。そのページは日本語（Shift JIS）で文字化けなく表示されています。ソースを確認したところ、文字化けが発生しました。また、vbscriptとなんらかFormツールで開発したページのようです。

Comment: 「ソースの表示」をクリックしたところ、デバッガーの下に該当のソースが表示されました。そのエンコードは不明です。

Comment: なるほど。では、後から来た人でもそのあたりがわかりやすくなるように、質問に追記してくださいませんでしょうか？　質問の下の [編集] ボタンから編集ができます。できれば、どのようなツールを用いた上で「ソースの表示」をしたのか、などの情報もあると良いのではないかと思います。

Comment: ソース上の日本語は全て文字化けしているのでしょうか。

Comment: 編集しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: IEの「ソースを表示」ということは、メモ帳などのエディタでソースを閲覧しているということでしょうか？　そうだとして、どういう名前のエディタか分かりますか？

Comment: 最初はそのままIE上で確認しました。あとはHTMLページに組んで、いくつかのエンコードで試しましたが、文字化けのままです。

Comment: 見せられる範囲で構いませんので、スクショを添付していただけませんでしょうか？　画像さえあれば、質問編集画面の上の方にある「画像」ボタンから直接添付できます。

Comment: というのも、どういうビューワでどのように文字化けしているか確認したいためです。